# How to see console output after attaching to running process in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, console-application, qt-creator

I have a hierarchy of Qt-based apps on Windows. One GUI app has started another console app (but without visible console window) via [`QProcess::startDetached`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1). I would like to attach to this console app with debugger from the QtCreator. But after attaching I don't see any console output (the standard "Application output" tab <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is empty).

When I run console app separately from the QtCreator I see the "qtcreator_process_stub.exe console" which shows me all output.

Is there a way to see console output after attaching to the running process in my case, i.e. without restarting it as separate app?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

To get a QProcess output, it must be "part" of you app: this seems not possible using startDetached.

---

If, instead, you have an instance of QProcess in your GUI app, you can run the process using the start() method. At this point you can lean on the signals emitted when something is printed on standard output/error:

```
QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput()

QProcess::readyReadStandardError()
```

To get the text, connect them to a slot, and then invoke:

```
process->readAllStandardOutput()

process->readAllStandardError()
```

Comment: Are you suggesting me to read console output via `QProcess`? My question is about how to get console output in QtCreator IDE, not on the app which created `QProcess` object.

Comment: I have edited the answer but basically yes, you have to retrieve the data through
 the QProcess, then print it out with qDebug() to see it on the QtCreator output.